# Spellchecking on comment box is annoying

Tags: feature-request, comments, user-interface, spelling

I'm not sure if this is something caused by a change on Stack Overflow, or a browser update (I'm using Google Chrome 110), but comment boxes now have squiggly red underlines for <s>spelling mistakes</s> code and technical jargon:

[image: squiggly red underlines]

These are distracting and annoying, because comments on Stack Overflow are very likely to intentionally contain "words" that aren't in a browser's spellcheck dictionary. This issue could be fixed by adding a [`spellcheck="false"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/spellcheck) attribute to the `textarea` element.

Comment: Stack Overflow doesn't have a built-in spell-checker

Comment: And we're reminded of it nearly every time we read something that users have typed in.

Comment: @Dharman I know; browsers do, and it's controlled by the `spellcheck` attribute on the HTML element, as I mentioned. I'm saying Stack Overflow's user interface would be better if this attribute were present. Do you have an argument for why it would not be better?

Comment: ys i hve thge argumnt.

Comment: ... well because then there would be no red squiggly lines pointing out spelling mistakes I'm making  :/ The thing actually has a function.

Comment: [Test input](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/definitely#Adverb): defenatly, defenetly, defenitely, defenitly, defently, Defently, deffinatly, Deffinatly, deffinetely, deffinetly, deffinitly, deffo, defiantly, defiently, definately, definatily, definatly, Definatly, definently, definetely, definetily, definetley, definetly, definiately, definietly, defininetly, definiteley, definitelly, definitelt, Definitely, definitetly, definitley, definitly, Definitly, definively, defintely, defintitely, defo, Defo, denitely, and diffenately.

Comment: A spellchecker is not useful if it has such a high false positive rate. I see very few spelling mistakes in Stack Overflow comments in my usual experience, but lots and lots of code and technical terms that aren't in dictionaries. Perhaps your experience is different, or perhaps you claim that the spellchecker is the reason that all of those comments I see don't have spelling problems (though as I mentioned, the red squiggles are only newly visible to me, using a very popular browser). But the false positive rate must be well above 90%, which I would say makes it worse than useless.

Comment: In Firefox's spellchecker, you can place the cursor in a word, right-click and select *"Add to Dictionary"* to drastically bring down the false positive rate.

Comment: "*I see very few spelling mistakes in Stack Overflow comments*" Is that because humans are perfect at spelling in one of the most complicated languages on earth, or because their computer told them their spelling was wrong and helped them fix it? Either way, it's not an autowrecker, you don't have to fix the spelling, it just let's you know you may want to.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Thanks, but I don't really want to add the words "mut", "Vec", "usize" and "PeterMortensen" to my browser's spellchecking dictionary, and the argument I'm making is that this is a bad user interface decision (if it is indeed intentional, rather than just something that happened due to browsers changing) so telling me that I can fix it just for myself is not really an answer. If Stack Overflow's official position is that red squiggles under words like "userscript" are actually good, then I will probably look to fix this with a userscript.

Comment: @vandench It lets me know that I may want to, and it is wrong 90%+ of the time, probably more like 99%+. Something that is wrong that often is not helpful.

Comment: I spellcheck words on Stack Overflow and other communities daily when I submit commentary and even my answers.  I go as far as using Grammarly to verify all my comments and answers are grammatically correct.  I used the built-in spellcheck three times while submitting this comment.  Preventing users from being able to spellcheck seems like a horrible idea.

Answer (score 23):

No. Spellchecker's ar a usful toal, ant we shuldnt be diabeling dem bai defult.

If you don't want a spellchecker, disable it in your browser.

Comment: If spellcheck was disabled, I suspect Jon Skeet, would submit answers like this.

Comment: I believe Jon Skeet has been writing answers on Stack Overflow since before spellcheckers were built into major browsers, and I also believe that Stack Overflow more broadly was not full of answers written like this one before that time. Personally I cannot define a tool as "useful" if almost every time it asks for my attention it is wrong. But judging by the number of downvotes, it seems everyone else is either really this bad at spelling, or really not annoyed by the bright red squiggly lines under all code and URLs. (And the word "downvotes" gets the red squiggle, funnily enough.)

Comment: @kaya3 Just speaking for me here, but I started to ignore the red squiggly lines, because my browser is not in english, but I'm writing this comment in english, meaning [essentially *everything*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xm0VC.png) is underlined red. I suspect many people are not native english speakers / don't have their browser set to english, so they just ignore them.

Comment: @Lino That is my idea of hell. I salute you and anyone else who puts up with this in order to participate here.

Comment: @kaya3 At least for me it is a form of practicing [selective ignorance](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Selective%20Ignorance). Which I've adapted over the years. For you, a userscript might help, as I'm certain Stack Overflow won't fix this.

Comment: @Lino: That can be avoided by installing extra dictionaries (at least in Firefox). And the active set can be changed on the fly, by right-click (or the context menu key), e.g. *Languages* → *English (United Kingdom)*. Using an active set of American English and British English ***at the same time*** will bring down the number of squiggles.

Answer (score 5):

The true annoyance is that Chrome does not support blacklisting/whitelisting sites so you can control on which sites it is active, or to allow you to configure the color of the squiggly line so it is less obtuse. It's just an on/off switch. Perhaps there is an extension which does provide such options, then you can disable the built-in spellchecker and use the extension instead.

Instructing Stack Overflow to disable it is not a solution, because it impacts other people as well. In the past personal preferences (like a dark mode) were implemented with a browser userscript, perhaps that is possible here as well.

Any claims about the built-in spellchecker being wrong I cannot personally support in any case, certainly not when you start to pull percentages in the high 90's out of thin air. It works just fine for me. Although I'd wish it would be less pedantic about UK/US spelling differences.

Comment: "Wrong" means it underlines something that is not spelled incorrectly. Code is written very frequently in comments, and I think it's totally plausible that on Stack Overflow, words like "mut" and "usize" (which are wrongly underlined) are 9+ times as common as actual spelling mistakes (which would be correctly underlined). I would be very surprised if that were not the case. Clearly, judging from the votes, other people find these squiggly lines helpful or at least not annoying, which is astonishing to me - does everyone else on SO really make spelling errors more often than they write code?

Comment: @kaya3 - Why are you submitting code as a comment? A comment should contain feedback about the question or answer, if you are submitting a lot of code as commentary, it's very likely that code should be an answer instead.

Comment: @SecurityHound ... because feedback on questions and answers with code often involves code? Things like variable names, type names, function/method names. Also technical jargon (like "userscript"), URLs, user names... I've been seeing these red squiggles all day and they haven't helped me once.

Comment: Re *"...less pedantic about UK/US spelling differences"*: If ***both*** dictionaries are in the active set, it will be (Firefox. I *think* using more than one dictionary at a time is a newer feature; I am not sure. (It may imply having to install an extra dictionary. Fortunately, the installation page is now linked directly from the same context menu (*Languages* → *Add Dictionaries*)).).

Comment: @PeterMortensen if that works, you are a god among men.